# Flask: How to upload a user file into Google Cloud Storage using upload_blob

Tags: python, file, flask, google-cloud-platform, temporary-files

I'm using Flask to make a web application and I want to upload a user input file to Google Storage Cloud. I'm using Heroku to host my web app and I don't know how to save files on Heroku's temporary storage so I'm trying to use tempfile to store the file in a directory and then access the directory to upload the file.

When I try to do that, I get this error: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\[MyName]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpbpom7ull'`

Here is my code I'm working with, if anyone has any other way to upload a FileStorage object to the Google Storage cloud or a way to access the saved file, that would be very appreciated!

```
# File is currently a "FileStorage" object from werkzeug, gotten by doing
# file = request.files["filename"]
tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
file.name = filename
file.save(tempdir)

upload_blob(BUCKET_NAME,filename,filename)
```

Answer (score 3):

Following up on yesterday's [Flask: Could not authenticate question the Google Cloud Storage client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70573077/flask-could-not-authenticate-the-google-cloud-storage-client), you can use werkzeug's [FileStorage](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage) object as described in the Flask-GoogleStorage [usage](https://flask-googlestorage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#usage):

Assuming you a have a file `hellofreddie.txt` in the working directory:

`hellofreddie.txt`:

```
Hello Freddie!
```

You can then `open` it, create a `FileStorage` object and then use the `save` on Bucket object (`files`):

```py
from datetime import timedelta

from flask import Flask
from flask_googlestorage import GoogleStorage, Bucket
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage

import os


files = Bucket("files")
storage = GoogleStorage(files)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    GOOGLE_STORAGE_LOCAL_DEST = app.instance_path,
    GOOGLE_STORAGE_SIGNATURE = {"expiration": timedelta(minutes=5)},
    GOOGLE_STORAGE_FILES_BUCKET = os.getenv("BUCKET")
)
storage.init_app(app)

with app.app_context():
    with open("hellofreddie.txt","rb") as f:
        file = FileStorage(f)
        filename = files.save(file)
```

After the code has run, you will see a UUID-named equivalent created in Cloud Storage.

You can use the storage browser or `gsutil`:

```sh
gsutil ls gs://${BUCKET}
gs://{BUCKET}/361ea9ea-5599-4ff2-84d1-3fe1a802ac08.txt
```

> **NOTE** I was unable to resolve an issue trying to `print` either `files.url(filename)` or `files.signed_url(filename)`. These methods **correctly** return the Cloud Storage Object but as [`PurePosixPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePosixPath)`('f3745268-5c95-4c61-a892-09c0de556635.txt')`. My Python naivete.

Answer (score 1):

I've realized my error, I was trying to use file.save() to a folder and not to an actual file, my code has been updated to

```
tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    file.name = filename
    file.save(tempdir + "/" + filename)

    upload_blob(BUCKET_NAME,tempdir + "/" + filename,filename)
```

Thank you to [PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434764/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied)